# What is the best way to share/distribute Excel macro?

Tags: excel, vba, share, distribute

I wrote the macro in Excel and want to distribute it to the users. Once opened I want the macro to add itself as a toolbar and then to be always visible  whenever the Excel is opened. So the macro can be conveniently accessed used from all workbooks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IMHO, the easiest way is to create an **add-in** with your code and give it to the users.

See [this link on ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm) to learn how to build addins.

Comment: Prevent linkrot! Post the pertinent details of any outside links here and credit the original author.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant here because I won't copy/paste the whole ozgrid page (which will be far relevant there than here). As far as I can tell and considering the OP's question, there is no *specific relevant* information that would be more interesting here than a link to the page. If I missed anything, please tell me what kind of information I should have copied here so that I can learn.

Comment: +1, and the links at Ozgrid are very stable - trust me.

Comment: Yeah, there are some sites worth worrying about, but Ozgrid is not one of them :)

Answer (score 1):

For Sub's tied to toolbars an Addin - as said by JMax - would be my choice. For formulae specific to your business a regular empty Excel file with one or more modules containing Function Xxx(), placed in the Autostart folder would be sufficient.

A server directory which is added to the user's path of Autostart folders is an easy way to auto-distribute formulae.

I am using the latter for instance for IP address calculations