# How to distribute VBA code in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I wrote VBA code that updates changes made in Excel to a database (SQL server).
How can I distribute this code to other users?
I stored the changed values in an array using the Worksheet_Change subroutine.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   'add value to array
End sub
```

I also have code to update the database:

```
Sub update_database()
  'update database
End sub
```

I stored both subroutines in the ***sheet1*** code.

How can I distribute this **macro** without the user copying and pasting my code?
I know that I can put my macro in quick link. But I don't know how to deal with the Worksheet_Change procedure which I think is bound to the sheet.

Comment: you can use vba event in addins - see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx) for more information and this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596623/what-is-the-best-way-to-share-distribute-excel-macro/7597071#7597071) to distribute vba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your code in an Addin and distribute that.

Note: to make the addin respond to all `Worksheet_Change events`, see [How can an Excel Add-In respond to events in any worksheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858691/how-can-an-excel-add-in-respond-to-events-in-any-worksheet)