# Easiest way to allow others to install an Excel (2011) macro?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I wrote a macro from scratch but would like to have non-technical people install/run it at ease.  I'm unfortunately not onsite so I was hoping to defer the hassle to myself and offer them a one-(or few)-click solution.  Any advice?

This Stack Overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596623/what-is-the-best-way-to-share-distribute-excel-macro) seemed to be one of the better solutions, and this is still probably too complicated for my clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for a one click solution, you are going to want to create an add-in and then an installer.  This guide covers this pretty well in depth:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx#Create

If you don't want to do that, then the easiest way is to just copy/paste the macro (if it is not too complex) into each user's workbook or personal.xls if it needs to be used in multiple workbooks.